# Is the unit sphere in product topology a compact set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the product topology. I know that $A$ is metrizable and complete, but is the set $\{v\in A: \Vert v \Vert_\infty=1\} $ compact, where $\Vert \Vert_\infty$ is the sup norm?

Comment: There was a related question earlier about $[0,1]\times[0,1/2]\times\cdots[0,1/n]\times\cdots$ being compact in $\mathcal{l}^2$. It was shown to be compact. The argument used the existence of a continuous function.

Comment: Hint-Tychonoff's Theorem.

Comment: The obvious solution is to invoke Tychonoff's theorem, although that strikes me as probably overkill in this situation.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha how can we write  $\{v\in A: \Vert v \Vert_\infty=1\} $  as a product of compact sets?

Comment: @Antonis we can't, but the whole space is certainly compact. I was alluding to this fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is compact and Hausdorff, so its compact subsets are precisely its closed subsets. Every non-empty open set in $A$ contains points of norm $1$, so the set of points of norm $1$ is dense in $A$. Since the set of points of norm $1$ is not all of $A$, it’s not closed in $A$ and therefore is not compact.

Comment: What do you mean is that the set I defined is dense in $A$?

Comment: @Antonis: Yes, exactly. I’ve now made that explicit in my answer.

Comment: Is the set $\{v\in A: \Vert v \Vert_\infty=1, |v_k|\geq 1/2\} $  compact, where $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed? I just read it in a paper.

Comment: @Antonis: Do you mean that $|v_k|\ge\frac12$ for *all* $k$?

Comment: No look here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1176.pdf at page 10 under equation 36.

Comment: @Antonis: Unless I’m misunderstanding something (and I’ve not tried to read the whole thing), that set is *not* compact in the product topology if $I$ is infinite. Tikhonov’s theorem applies to show that $\Bbb T^I$ is compact, but the other set is not a product.

Comment: @Antonis: You’re very welcome.